# Formatting percentages in ASP.NET C# databinding using Eval

Tags: c#, asp.net

There is a col in a database that is declare as decimal 4 precision 3. I need to multiply this number by 100 (I am doing that in the stored procedure query) and display it as a decimal with only significant zeros after the decimal point. If the resulting value is less than 1%, I suppose it should be displayed with a 0 *before* the decimal. The display should include a % mark. For example:

```
 100 %
 99.1 %
 0.1 %
 56 %
 0 %
```

The web page is using data binding:

```
 <asp:Label ID="lblTMLY_POL_HLDER_NOTC_PCT" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DECIMAL_COL_PREC_4_SCALE_3") %>'></asp:Label>
```

I suppose I'd probably have an easier time handling this in the Data Bound Item even and using string formatting functions there. Ideally, I'd like to know what format string in the markup to use and how one would handle this in the code behind.

```
  <asp:Label ID="lblTMLY_POL_HLDER_NOTC_PCT" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DECIMAL_COL_PREC_4_SCALE_3","{00:??????}") %>'></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are looking for?

[image]

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Id" DataField="Id" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Actual Value" DataField="Total" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Using Bound Field" DataField="Total" 
            DataFormatString="{0:0.### %}" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Using Eval">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" 
                    Text='<%# string.Format("{0:0.### %}", Eval("Total")) %>'>
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

private class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var items = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item {Id = 1, Name = "One", Total = 1.0M},
            new Item {Id = 2, Name = "Two", Total = 0.2M},
            new Item {Id = 3, Name = "Three", Total = 0.03M},
            new Item {Id = 4, Name = "Four", Total = 0.004M},
            new Item {Id = 5, Name = "Five", Total = 0.0005M},
            new Item {Id = 6, Name = "Six", Total = 0.00006M},
        };

    GridView1.DataSource = items;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: I was looking to display it as a decimal with only significant zeros after the decimal point as shown in the example. Sorry, shouldn't have down voted any answer attempt, especially without an explanation. Edit the reply and I'll correct , i can't modify until you answer is updated.

Comment: My bad! I miss read your question. I updated the answer - `{0:0.### %}`. Here are more examples - http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/

Comment: Thanks. I think String.Format("{0:0.##}", 123.0); is the answer for the code behind approach, but I was really looking for a solution using Eval in the markup.

Comment: If you want to use Eval only, you can just use `<%# Eval("Total", "{0:0.##%}") %>`. However, you need `%` which is the purpose of display decimal value (less than 1) into percentage.